# How to replace or insert if a document is not found in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
 address.update(
     
        {creator:req.userData.unique_SHOP},
        {$setOnInsert:PassAddress},
        
         {
          upsert:true,
         } 
       
    
    )
```

this is my query

- `address` = schema
- `creator` is the key that i'm trying to match
- `passAddress` has the all elements of the documents

```
 const PassAddress = new address({
    firstname:req.body.firstname,
    lastname:req.body.lastname,
    phone:req.body.phone,
    zip:req.body.zip,
    address1:req.body.address1,
    address2:req.body.address2,
    city:req.body.city,
    state:req.body.state,
    country:req.body.country,
    creator:req.userData.unique_SHOP
  });
```

any help?i am new to mongodb

Comment: just use `$set` instead of `$setOnInsert`.

Comment: nope @turivishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work!

```
const PassAddress = new address({
    firstname:req.body.firstname,
    lastname:req.body.lastname,
    phone:req.body.phone,
    zip:req.body.zip,
    address1:req.body.address1,
    address2:req.body.address2,
    city:req.body.city,
    state:req.body.state,
    country:req.body.country,
    creator:req.userData.unique_SHOP
  });

address.findOneAndUpdate(
    {creator:req.userData.unique_SHOP}, // find a document with that filter
    PassAddress, // document to insert when nothing was found
    {upsert: true, new: true}, // options
    function (err, doc) { // callback
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // handle document
        }
    }
);
```

Reference : https://silvantroxler.ch/2016/insert-or-update-with-mongodb-and-mongoose/

Answer (score 1):

If passAddress has all the documents you want to insert of update just use simple update with upsert field

```
db.collection.update(<query>, <update>,{upsert: true)

//in your case
address.update(
        {creator:req.userData.unique_SHOP},
         passAddress,
         { 
           upsert:true,
         }            
    )
```

Comment: thanks,i know this is correct but @radial's answer was working!